# Oracle Linux 6.1 guest on Virtualbox 4.1 can't connect to network

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, virtualbox

I just installed VirtualBox 4.1 on my Windows system, and then added a Solaris 11 Express guest and an Oracle Linux 6.1 guest. Both installs went smoothly.  But while the Solaris 11 guest has network access, the Oracle Linux box can't connect to the network.

Both guests are using the same default network settings (NAT). I'm at a loss -- not sure what I need to configure on the OL6.1 side.

To test basic network connectivity, I tried: `ping www.google.com`. No problems with the Solaris guest. On the OL6.1 guest:

```
    # ping www.google.com
    ping: unknown host www.google.com
    # ping 209.85.175.99
    connect: Network is unreachable
```

Is there some sort of network setup that's required on OL6.1 that wasn't required on Solaris11? Thanks in advance.

output from `ifconfig -a`:

```
    # ifconfig -a
    eth0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr  08:00:27:8E:A1:42
            inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe8e:a142/64 Scope:Link
            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
            RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
            RX bytes:0 (0.0 b) TX bytes:328 (328.0 b)

    lo      Link encap: Local Loopback
            inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0
            inet6addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
            UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
            RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen: 0
            RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

Comment: Please post the output of `ifconfig -a`. During the installation, did you leave the IPv4 settings on the automatic method (step 10 in the [instructions](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/linux/OracleLinux6Installation.php))?

Comment: During installation, I was never given the option to configure the network (step 10 in your instructions). I'm running 6.1; maybe I should go back and try 6.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that Oracle Linux is heavily based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux, the network configuration is probably the same. If you didn't need to enter any network parameters during the installation of Solaris, then you're picking up a network address through [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol). There isn't much call for doing anything else in a NATted virtual machine anyway.

To [configure a DHCP client](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-dhcp-configuring-client.html) on RHEL, edit the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` to contain the following lines:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
```

Or you can use [Network Manager](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-NetworkManager.html) instead (it'll give you the same kind of network configuration through a desktop icon that Solaris has, and in fact I believe it is more powerful than Solaris's — not that you really need that in a VM).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the specified default router might be incorrect.  To find out, do

```
 netstat -r
```

to see the routing table.  Locate the default route (destination 0.0.0.0), and then ping the default router...i.e.

```
 ping 10.0.0.1
```

Comment: on the OL6.1 guest, netstat -r just displays the header as output; no entries in the routing tables.  On the Solaris guest, netstat -r displays info about the default router.

Comment: Unlikely (and that's confirmed by the `ifconfig` output). On simple setups, it's rare that the routing is wrong; here, as usual, the issue is that there's no IP connectivity at all.

Answer (score 0):

Centos/RHEL

Edit the file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/interface

ONBOOT=yes

and restart network

it should work !!